# resize brightcove video player

Tags: javascript, brightcove

Is there an idea I could use to resize brightcove video player so that it fits into the browser window according to the resized height and width. It should work for both flash and HTML5 mode. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Maybe this might help: [css-elastic-videos](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this issue:

```
var brightcove_video_container = $( "#brightcove-video-container" ).brightcoveVideo({ 
    "playerID": "3715052728001",    "@videoPlayer": liveStream.id,      "autoStart": true, 
    "templateReadyHandler": function(){
        //resize for ipad
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
            $("#brightcove-video-container").data( "brightcoveVideo" ).experience.setSize( $("#brightcove-video-container").width(), $("#brightcove-video-container").height() );                           
        }, false);
    } 
});
```